# Error >> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'categoryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, e-commerce

```cs
public ActionResult UpdateCategory(int categoryId)
{
    CategoryDetail cd;
    if (categoryId != null)
    {
        cd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryDetail>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().GetFirstorDefault(categoryId)));
    }
    else
    {
        cd = new CategoryDetail();
    }
    return View("UpdateCategory", cd);
}
```

cant able to add the product while adding the error below occurs

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'categoryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateCategory(Int32)' in 'OnlineShoppingStore.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable typ

Comment: Why are you serializing to JSON and *immediately* deserializing? Aside from anything else, the code in the first branch of the `if` block is one *very* long statement... it would be easier to understand and debug if you would split it into multiple statements - and give us the full stack trace of the error instead of just the message.

Comment: How can i solve this can you please explain

Comment: Well you could *start* be doing what I've already said: 1) split your huge statement into multiple statements for clarity. 2) Explain why you're serializing and then immediately deserializing. 3) Provide the full stack trace instead of the error message.